# How can I animate it like walking on a canvas drawn between two points

Tags: android, animation, canvas, bitmap, navigation

The route is being updated as new locations arrive. Each location is drawn as a `Bitmap` image on the canvas.

```
 if (!routeList.isEmpty() && !nodeList.isEmpty()) {

            // draw route
            for (int i = 0; i < routeList.size() - 1; i++) {

                PointF goal3 = new PointF(nodeList.get(routeList.get(i)).x, nodeList.get(routeList.get(i)).y);
                PointF goal4 = new PointF(nodeList.get(routeList.get(i + 1)).x, nodeList.get(routeList.get(i + 1)).y);

                sourceToViewCoord(goal3, vPin5);
                sourceToViewCoord(goal4, vPin6);

                path.moveTo(vPin5.x, vPin5.y);
                path.lineTo(vPin6.x, vPin6.y);                 
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

            }

            PointF goal1 = new PointF(nodeList.get(routeList.get(0)).x, nodeList.get(routeList.get(0)).y);

            sourceToViewCoord(goal1, vPin3);

            float vX1 = vPin3.x - (location_img.getWidth() / 2);
            float vY1 = vPin3.y - location_img.getHeight() / 2;

            canvas.drawBitmap(location_img, vX1, vY1, paint);//Location drawing on canvas as a bitmap(image)

            PointF goal2 = new PointF(nodeList.get(routeList.get(routeList.size() - 1)).x, nodeList.get(routeList.get(routeList.size() - 1)).y);


            sourceToViewCoord(goal2, vPin4);

            float vX2 = vPin4.x - (pin_red.getWidth() / 2);
            float vY2 = vPin4.y - pin_red.getHeight();

            canvas.drawBitmap(pin_red, vX2, vY2, paint);//Arrival point is drawn on the canvas as a bitmap(image)

        }
```

Comment: please explain more

Comment: Since the location is plotted on the map as image, it is jumping on the path on the map when other location information arrived. How can I animate a passage like navigating on the road when other location information arrives on the road between two locations? @SanjayKumar

Comment: So what you want i understand. You have an Image of map. Say, your current location is A. You are showing an icon for current location. If you get location B. You directly jump to location B. If you want animation from A to B than you have to get all Points between A to B. So that you move one by one from A to B.

Comment: Yes, as you understand. I thought so, but I wondered if there was any other way, like an animation transition from A to B point.@SanjayKumar

Comment: yes but it will be linear animation, You can say in a straight line. For this you will have to get all point on the line which lie on line made by point A and B. A and B will be the end point of line